# Time complexity 2-opt method

Tags: algorithms, heuristics, routing

I'm doing a practice test for a course on routing problems. There's a question asking to infere the time complexity of the 2-opt method.

I can see that the complexity per iteration is in $O(n^2)$ because you need to check all combinations of 2 arcs. I don't know how to calculate the worst case number of iterations though. The paper we got doesn't say anything about it's tc, so i'm kind of stuck here.

How do i calculate this?

Comment: It would help if you explained the 2-opt method and what problem it is supposed to solve.